# Export content of columns in Total Commander

Tags: total-commander

How I can export full table of files with all viewable columns (like a information plug-ins) to a text file/csv file? Is it possible? I know only way for obtaining selected file list without any columns.

Answer (score 6):

You may use *Mark->Copy To Clipboard With All Details* command to obtain the selected file list with all details in TAB-separated format.

Comment: Thank you I just haven't menu commands like this. I manually added menu item with command  like cm_SaveDetailsToFile from Totalcmd.inc list

Comment: Good solution. Strange that you don't have the menu command -- in my installation it presents (version 7.56a).

Comment: I don't have this command because I use fan custom bundle of Total Commander with many awesome commands but without Mark extensions

Comment: Does total comander has information about line number there search was succesful?