# Windows 8 : export directory's detail content to text

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, metadata

Is there a tool (a program, or commandlet or whatever) that would allow me to export the metadata of files in a directory with "details" view ? This is for Windows 8, but in case one exists for earlier versions of windows I'm interested too.

What I want to do is, for example, open a directory with a bunch of videos. Choose columns such as dimensions, bitrate, framerate, etc. And have that metadata exported to a nice format (preferrably text).

For videos I know there are specific tools that do it. I also know of tools that work well for audio files or images. But windows is able to handle a lot of metadata for many types of files, so a tool that could take advantage of this would be cool.

I guess my question is similar to this one, but for explorer instead of total commander: [Export content of columns in Total Commander](https://superuser.com/questions/360598/export-content-of-columns-in-total-commander) .

Comment: If media file metadata is what you're interested in, Explorer's columns are barely adequate. Why don't you use something like MediaInfo instead? It has a GUI and can also be invoked from the command line. If you want something though  that will work irrespective of file type, that'll require a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html)'s *Text Capture* feature should help you here. It supports:

```
Window          Region              Scrolling Window
Active Window   Fixed Region        Scrolling Active Window
Full Screen     Object              Clipboard Rich
All-in-One      Custom Scroll       Text Formatting
```

There's also [HyperSnap](http://www.hyperionics.com)'s similar *TextSnap* feature which I have used successfully. I'm sure there are other screen-capture utilities with similar features.

Comment: Not very clean solution, but it works (can become problematic for directories where the contents is larger than what can be displayed on a single screen though). Thanks.

Comment: I believe Scrolling Window Capture should be able to handle that as well.

Answer (score 0):

For audio or video files, you can use maplyer for windows (available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/mplayer-win32/) and use something like this to extract information you can later parse:

```
mplayer.exe -ao null -vo null -endpos 0 -v directory > file.txt
```